# How to debug script that is calling other scripts

Tags: powershell, debugging

I have PowerShell script (not written by me) that during execution do some prep work and calls few other scripts. I'm interested so see the values of some variables within those scripts. How can I do it?

How to see with values are assigned to `$b` while executing `MainScript.ps1`?

`MainScript.ps1` content:

```
$a = Get-Process
.\Worker.ps1
```

`Worker.ps1` content:

```
foreach ($b in $a) {
    # do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open both scripts in PowerShell ISE and set a desired breakpoint in Worker.ps1 and and run MainScript.ps1. It will hit the breakpoint the same way if you would execute it by itself.

Answer (score -1):

Download [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and install Powershell extension that will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PowerShell ISE to debug.